# Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord where property is not blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am trying to find records where a specified property is not empty or blank. Since it is a string it is not nil in the database.

```
Post.where(:sourceurl != '')
```

The above seems like it should work but I still get records returned where the source_url property is empty. What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

try this

```
Post.where("sourceurl <> ''")
```

Comment: @steel please read the question...the question is for string...for integer you can use `Post.where("sourceurl is not null")`

Comment: Seems to not work postgres ..i posted what worked for me anyway!

Answer (score 45):

ActiveRecord (in Rails 3 and 4, i think) allows for checking multiple conditions by passing an Array as an argument. So if you wanted to check for both `nil` and `''`, you can use:

```
where(sourceurl: [nil, ''])
```

This will generate an SQL conditional like:

```
(sourceurl IS NULL OR sourceurl = '')
```

In Rails 4, you can check for the negative condition with .not, so for the original question, you could do:

```
Post.where.not(sourceurl: [nil, ''])
```

.not has a bit of magic that makes it advantageous to a pure SQL query because it works across databases, does NOT NULL queries automatically, and a few more things as explained here: [where.not explained](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/activerecords-wherenot)

Comment: Would you mind explaining a bit what it does? Just putting some code in an answer isn't that helpful.

Comment: Thanks for fixing my code formatting; been awhile since I answered a question. Let me edit the answer.

Comment: Been working with Rails for 10 years now and you just blew my mind. Not sure how I didn't know that already. I've always resorted to raw SQL like `.where( "posts.sourceurl IS NULL OR posts.sourceurl = ''" )`. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

**Rails 4**

Active Record condition:

```
where.not(value: '')
```

Scope:

```
scope :myscope, -> { where.not(value: '') }
```

Comment: Don't use. In Rails 4 this will produce `value != NULL`

Answer (score 4):

The reason your code doesn't work is that your parameter to `#where` is

```
:sourceurl != ''
```

which evaluates to `true`, as `:sourceurl` (the symbol) is not equal to `''` (an empty string). Thus your code is the same as

```
Post.where(true)
```

To elaborate on abhas's answer, both MySQL and PostgreSQL will accept `!=` and `<>` as equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

If that field is NULL by default in your database, I think the better way to resolve it to use plain SQL:

```
Post.where("sourceurl is not null")
```

Comment: this would include blanks.

Answer (score 3):

In postgresql to catch both empty string and nil you can do:

```
where("coalesce(sourceurl, '') != ''")
```

Comment: Detailed here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-conditional.html Section 9.13.2